# Show Field with Asterick if Bool value is true in Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating a table in my Razor view that if a bool value is true then show an asterick next to one of the fields.  The code I have looks correct but it is coming out blank on all rows.  It should be the number in that field if false and the number in that field* if true.

Here is the code:

```
@{ 
     string ToDisplay = item.MinimumOnHandQuantity.ToString();
     if (item.UseForecast)
     {
           ToDisplay += "*";
     }
}
@Html.Display(ToDisplay)
```

Comment: When you debug this, what is ToDisplay? Is it populated?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@{ 
     string ToDisplay = item.MinimumOnHandQuantity.ToString();
     if (item.UseForecast)
     {
           ToDisplay += "*";
     }
}
@Html.Raw(ToDisplay)
```

Comment: Thank you that is half way there.  The field is now showing but the Asterisk is not showing where it is supposed to.

Comment: @djblois try replacing astrick with &#42; It's working for me in latest mvc 5, which version you are using?

Comment: I just realized, at least partially, why it isn't working.  It is never finding item.UseForecast as true even though there are cases when it is true.

Comment: @djblois hmm, Html.Raw will accept both * and &#42; and show a astrick.

Comment: no I mean it is never getting to the `ToDisplay += "*";` statement because it is never recognizing item.UseForecast as true.

Comment: @djblois yup, got it.